# Closed sets, boundary, topology.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Let A be a closed subset of the real numbers. It is always possible to find a subset B of the real numbers such that A is equal to the boundary of B? Prove if true, find a counterexample if not.

I think it's false but have no idea how to find a counterexample. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you show us what you have tried perhaps someone can use your work as a basis for a hint or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $A$, let $B$ be any countable dense subset of $A$. (Such a $B$ exists; just take one point from each nonempty set of the form $A\cap(p,q)$ where $p<q$ are rational numbers.) So the closure of $B$ is $A$.  The interior of $B$ is empty, because $B$ is countable. So the boundary of $B$ is $A$.

Comment: Could you please expand on the part in brackets? I don't fully get what you mean.

Comment: @Eduardo There are only countably many rational numbers and therefore only countably many pairs of rational numbers. So the process I described will produce a countable set $B$. To see that it is dense in $A$, consider any point $a\in A$ and any interval $(a-h,a+h)$ around it; I must show that this interval contains a point of $B$. There are rational numbers $p$ and $q$ with $a-h<p<a<q<a+h$. So $A\cap(p,q)$ is nonempty (as it contains $a$), and therefore one of its elements was put into $B$. That element is in $B\cap(a-h,a+h)$, as required.